# Exe generated from setup.py bdist closes immediately. Is there any way to log or pause to analyze what's the exception?

Tags: python, setuptools

Created Setup file and used the following command to generate exe file.

```
python setup.py bdist
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're on windows you can use a cmd window to call it, and the output or error should show in the window

```
cd C:\yourlocation
yourexe.exe
```

Comment: Awesome !! This works. However, it shows distributionnot found error. If setup.py has name of project as "app" and version as "1.0". It complains distribution app==1.0 is not found.Strange!!